# How to split a row into columns for every three columns in excel?

Tags: excel, vba, vbscript

In Excel, how do I split a row into set of columns. The data in A1 : G1 should be in the first row, then A1: C1 would be same as the first row, D1: G1 should be from the end of the first row.This should continue till data in first row is limited to G1.

The data I have is like

```
 A     B       C             D           E  ...       AE           AF          AG            
 1     ab    2013/01/12     2013/02/23    233     2013/02/24    2013/03/11     500
 2     cd    2013/01/12     2013/02/23    233     2013/02/24    2013/03/11     343
 .
 . 
 200  XX     XXXX/XX/XX     XXXX/XX/XX    XX      XXXX/XX/XX    XXXX/XX/XX     XXX
```

I need this to be split into:

```
 A              B             C              D            E         
 1              ab          2013/01/12     2013/02/23    233
 .
 .
 1              ab          2013/02/24     2013/03/11    500


 2              cd          2013/01/12     2013/02/23    233 
 .
 .
 2              cd          2013/02/24     2013/03/11    343  
 .
 .
```

How can this be done in excel, I tried writing a vb script, but it didn't go anywhere. Can someone please help me with this.

Comment: That is the data present in the main row, the main rows does not end in G, it continues. I want to split all that data into several columns

Comment: Hi @pnuts the data I have extends from A to AG, I need to split and format it like I have shown here. I hope you understand the requirement. If not, please say, so that I could modify the question likewise.

Comment: @pnuts I have modified the question, hope it helps

Comment: What code did you try?  You need to post your code.

Comment: I am new to excel macros, @jbarker2160 I tried to record a macro doing it manually (copying and pasting), I was not able to automate it or make it work, so deleted it.

Comment: It looks more like the pattern repeats every six columns. Omitting the first column. Is that right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so it seems that you have two cells with static id and name then a series of three cells that show a pattern of `Date`,`Date`,`Number`. You want to bring everything to the right of the first two cells into repeating rows. This should do.

```
Sub split_and_stack()
    Dim c As Long, r As Long, lc As Long, lr As Long
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
    Set ws1 = ActiveSheet
    Sheets.Add after:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
    Set ws2 = Sheets(Sheets.Count)
    ws2.Cells(1, 1).Resize(1, 5) = Array("id", "name", "start", "end", "number")
    With ws1
        lr = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        lc = .Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        For r = 1 To lr
            For c = 3 To lc Step 3
                ws2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Resize(1, 2) = _
                  .Cells(r, 1).Resize(1, 2).Value
                ws2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 2).Resize(1, 3) = _
                  .Cells(r, c).Resize(1, 3).Value
            Next c
        Next r
    End With
End Sub
```

The following image may not show the dates correctly but you should get teh general idea. It is always a good idea not to provide ambiguous date that could be transcribed as either *mm/dd/yy* or *dd/mm/yy* when supplying sample data.

[image]